# Update binding after server response / How do I selectively update bindings?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-digest

I'm trying to prevent the value of a model from updating in a form.

For example :

I have a payment details form that lists the user's saved information (name, address etc) along with the form that is used to edit the same information.

I've been experimenting using the :: for one time binding as I don't want the displayed information to changed when input controls are changed (but I obviously want the models updated values so i can send them to the server for processing).

How do I update the displayed model values after the server responds that the changes have been saved, are ok etc? I can't seem to find a way to update the one time binding (as I'm guessing this is fully the intended functionality).

So I guess my question boils down to :

How do I selectively update bindings on some controls but not others?

Comment: This worked perfectly for me, thank you!

Comment: Will post it as an answer in a few minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you just want to display different vars.

You should try with a temporary model object (that is a copy of your object like "editedObject") and when you validate you will update the original object.

See it working in this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/oRdqRvn2QGqwZqEuE0qq?p=preview)

The editing space :

```
<input ng-model="editCopy.value"> <button ng-click="validateChange()">Change</button>
```

The ng-repeat :

```
<td ng-repeat="item in items" ng-click="editItem(item)">
    <a href="">{{item.value}}</a>
</td>
```

The functions :

```
$scope.editItem = function(item){
  $scope.editCopy = angular.copy(item);
  $scope.editingItem = item;
}
$scope.validateChange = function(){
  $http.get('index.html').success(function(){
    $scope.editingItem.value = $scope.editCopy.value;
  }); 
}
```